# Messed up method - if/then structure and string manipulation problems

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, logic, if-statement

I have a method that gets called any time a control on my view changes and should update a `UILabel`.  It has two `UITextField`s and two `UISlider`s.  First I check to see if either of the `UITextField`s are empty and if so, advise that they need to be filled in.  Otherwise I get the difference between the `UITextField`s' values and generate a couple of `float`s to use in my `NSString`s.

I get a warning that `message` is not used and I get an error about the `NSString`s (can't remember now exactly what - I'm not at my Mac...)

And even when I chopped the messages down to something simple that worked, when `delta == 0`, it does the `delta <= 0` message.

Oh, and the strings don't put the values in where the `%` signs are, they just print the `%` signs.

I've been hacking at this too long and need help...

```
- (void)updateAdvice {
    if ([chlorineSourceField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [poolVolumeField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSString *message =  [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter a chlorine source and pool volume."];
    }
    else {
        int delta = [targetLabel.text intValue] - [startingLabel.text intValue];
        float chlorineAmount = delta * [poolVolumeField.text intValue] * chlorineConstant;
        float percentRemove = (1 - ([targetLabel.text floatValue] / [startingLabel.text floatValue]));
        float gallonsRemove = percentRemove * [poolVolumeField.text intValue];
        if (delta == 0) {
            NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"No adjustments necessary.  You're on target"];
        }
        if (delta >= 0) {
            NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To increase FC by %dppm, add %3.1f oz of %@.", delta, chlorineAmount, chlorineSourceField.text];
        }
        if (delta <= 0) {
            NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You're above target already.  Replace %d%% or %d gallons of water - or just wait for it to come down.", percentRemove*100, gallonsRemove];
        }
    }
    adviceLabel.text = message;
    [message release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `else` part, thus all three `if` statements are being evaluated consecutively. If `delta == 0`, it will satisfy all three `if` statements. Thus, the last allocation will overwrite the previous two. (And you'll be leaking memory)

Also, your `message` variable is scoped as local to the `if` block it's declared into. You might want to move the `message` declaration at the function level scope.

As far as `%` not working, you are using the instance initializer [`initWithFormat`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-initWithFormat_locale_arguments_) with the syntax for the class initializer [`stringWithFormat`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:). `initWithFormat` takes the parameters for the formatted string in a separate parameter - `arguments:`. (Btw, it also requires `locale:`)

Comment: Duh, I don't want less-than-OR-equal, just less-than.  I'm new to the C world.  Can I just use `<` and `>` in the condition?  The `==` for equals throws me off =)

And do you know why the %d stuff wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes, you can use just `<` and `>`. I'd still add the `else` to the `if` blocks - you don't need all three to be evaluated always. Nope, I don't know why the %d part is not working.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out why the %d does not work. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'd trust that Apple documentation is more correct than any book out there. :-) But if it works just fine, it's your call. From your post and your comments, I was under the impression that it in fact _does not_ work, though.

Comment: When I said it worked, I meant that snippet in my comment works in the context of the sample program from the book - you're right in that my code does not work.  I checked out Apple's documentation and see what you mean.  They use `stringWithFormat:` in the way I am trying to make my strings.  I'll try that tonight at home and see.  Thanks again for the patient help.

Comment: Just FYI, Apple actually does have `initWithFormat` without requiring the `locale:` part.  The problem I had with the `%d` turned out to be that the thing that `%d` represented was a `float` and once I changed them to `%1.1f` the worked.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the `message` variable goes, it's scoped so it can't be used outside the `if`/`else` statement in which it is declared. You want to declare it *before* the `if` statement, so you can use it outside of the `if` statement. So something like this:

```
- (void)updateAdvice {
    NSString *message = nil;

    if ([chlorineSourceField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [poolVolumeField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        message =  [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter a chlorine source and pool volume."];
    }
    else {
        int delta = [targetLabel.text intValue] - [startingLabel.text intValue];
        float chlorineAmount = delta * [poolVolumeField.text intValue] * chlorineConstant;
        float percentRemove = (1 - ([targetLabel.text floatValue] / [startingLabel.text floatValue]));
        float gallonsRemove = percentRemove * [poolVolumeField.text intValue];
        if (delta == 0) {
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"No adjustments necessary.  You're on target"];
        }
        if (delta >= 0) {
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To increase FC by %dppm, add %3.1f oz of %@.", delta, chlorineAmount, chlorineSourceField.text];
        }
        if (delta <= 0) {
            message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You're above target already.  Replace %d%% or %d gallons of water - or just wait for it to come down.", percentRemove*100, gallonsRemove];
        }
    }
    adviceLabel.text = message;
    [message release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd never have figured that out without help! +1